# Returning std::function without making a copy

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

When returning a `std::function` from a function call, will the returned function be a copy of the function definition, or is it a reference to a function?

Background: I want to avoid bottle necks in some more or less performance sensitive part of my application. Thus I want to avoid allocations and copies where not required.

Example code:

```
typedef std::function<std::unique_ptr<ControllerResponse>(
    const std::vector<std::string> &pathComponents,
    const std::string &data,
    const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> &params)
> ControllerMethod;

ControllerMethod RouteIndex::findRoute(
    const std::vector<std::string> &pathComponents,
    const std::string &method,
    std::map<std::string, std::string> &requestParams) {
   // ... snip
   // suppose globalMap is a class member
   return globalMap.InstanceOfControllerMethod;
}
```

Will `findRoute()` return a copy or is `std::function` itself just a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ standard has this to say on `std::function` copy constructor:

> `function(const function& f);`
>
> Throws: shall not throw exceptions if `f`’s target is a specialization
>   of `reference_wrapper` or a function pointer. Otherwise, may throw
>   `bad_alloc` or any exception thrown by the copy constructor of the
>   stored callable object. [ Note: Implementations are encouraged to
>   avoid the use of dynamically allocated memory for small callable
>   objects, for example, where `f`’s target is an object holding only a
>   pointer or reference to an object and a member function pointer. — end
>   note ]

Make sure to read the note. If you keep your callbacks small, you should be able to copy `std::function` without it doing dynamic allocations.

So in your example, if `InstanceOfControllerMethod` is a function pointer, returning copy should not allocate memory. But if you want to put a member function pointer into it, you should be using lambda instead, as member function pointers in C++ are broken in many ways and are likely to be too large to fit into `std::function`:

```
std::function<void()> get_member_function(A *p)
{
    return [p]() { p->function(); };
}
```

Since such lambda only contains pointer `p`, it is guaranteed to fit in `std::function` instance, unlike member function pointer which can take 2 and more pointers.

Comment: "are too large to fit into `std::function`" - this is implementation-dependent, but I would be surprised if an implementation actually allocates for a pointer to member function. libstdc++ definitely doesn't, for instance.

Comment: @Barry `boost::function` is pretty large, should be able to fit everything, but I haven't seen `std::function` implementation that was that large. PS: changed to "likely to be too large"

Comment: Doesn't allocate on the big three: https://godbolt.org/z/pHy565

Comment: @Barry On MSVC member function pointer size depends on compiler arguments and might change depending on visibility of the class definition.

Comment: I was actually thinking about saving member function pointer plus object pointer - which is what typical callback consists of. This adds additional pointer to the size, while lambdas still takes a single pointer.

Comment: There’s no guarantee about the members of a lambda (although in practice you’re surely correct).

Answer (score 0):

You return a copy of `std::function` which is a class, not a reference.